# Create and modify collections in a package

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-packages, meteor-plugin

I'm trying to create a collection within a package (technically within a build plugin):

```
StaticCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null)
// also the same with Mongo.Collection('static')
StaticCollection.insert({stuff: 'thing'})
```

But this throws essentially this error:

```
   While loading plugin `compileMarkdownFiles` from package `faichenshing:collection-files`:
   packages/compileMarkdownFiles/plugin/compile-md.js:29:1: Mongo is not defined
   at Package (packages/compileMarkdownFiles/plugin/compile-md.js:29:1)
   at <runJavaScript-268>:121:4
   at <runJavaScript-268>:128:3
```

This didn't work as `Meteor.Collection` either.

Then I tried to import the `mongo` collection into my build plugin like this:

```
Package.registerBuildPlugin({
  name: "compileMarkdownFiles",
  use: ['spacebars-compiler', 'mongo'],
  // etc.
});
```

as well as in my `Package.onUse`:

```
api.use('mongo')
```

it throws this error:

```
While loading plugin `compileMarkdownFiles` from package `faichenshing:collection-files`:
   packages/ddp/stream_server.js:3:1: __meteor_runtime_config__ is not defined
   at self (packages/ddp/stream_server.js:3:1)
   at <runJavaScript-83>:694:4
   at <runJavaScript-83>:4779:3
```

No amount of searching for `__meteor_runtime_config__` has clarified this problem. It seems completely unrelated.

Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986354/correctly-using-collections-in-a-meteor-package/25987372#25987372) seem to not run into this problem at all.

The more I think about this the more convinced I am it has something to do with the existence of a build plugin in this code, but the collection definition isn't taking place within `registerSourceHandler` or anything.

Comment: Did you `api.export('StaticCollection')`?

Comment: It isn't an issue of accessing the variable from the actual app, the code above fails **at build time**, when the server is first being started.

Comment: @blaineh did you try giving the collection a name and not `null`? It can clarify if that's the issue try `StaticCollection = new Mongo.Collection('static')` and then we can figure out why inside a package you can't create local collections (didn't had to do it before)

Comment: Yes, same exact problem.